# Using the accessibility.js module with highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm trying to get the accessibility module to work with highcharter, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I'm trying to integrate it into a shiny app, so here's a very minimal example of where I'm at so far:

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
y <- c(1:4)
z <- c(4:7)

data <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    highchartOutput("chart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$chart <- renderHighchart({
hchart(data, "bubble", hcaes(x = x, y = y, size = z))%>%
    hc_add_dependency(name = "modules/accessibility.js")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But it still is not allowing me to tab through the bubbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I can't fix the tab option yet, I will check. sorry.

### Previous answer

This was a error from highcharter and it was fixed in the development version. Update and test with:

```
source("https://install-github.me/jbkunst/highcharter")
```

Now the accessibility pluging is included by default and you can configure using the `hc_accessibility` function with options described in the highcharts [API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility).

I tested using the [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/).

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = 1:3, type = "column") %>% 
  hc_accessibility(
    enabled = TRUE,
    keyboardNavigation = list(enabled = FALSE)
  )
```